# What is the distribution function of a measure? (in general case)

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}_+$.

What is the distribution function of $\mu$?

(I want to understand distribution functions in general case)

Thank you!

Comment: you should check the definition of generalised function for this and then see when measure(s) enters..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of distribution is a bit ambiguous: we can talk of distributions in the sense of Sobolev and Schwartz (they arise in functional analysis and PDEs, measures are particular cases thereof) or we can talk about distributions being another name for probability measures (often used e.g. in statistics). I guess that LB1's comment was about the former, whereas your question is about the latter. The distribution function of a probability measure on $\Bbb R$ (or actually any poset) is defined as $F_\mu(x) = \mu({y:y\leq x})$. So you can easily use the very same definition for any measure $\mu$.